# Compile error "Sendability of function types in instance method 'someMethod' does not match requirement in protocol 'SomeProtocol'" iOS 16 Swift 5.7

Tags: ios, swift, ios16, swift5.7

After updating to Xcode 14, iOS 16, Swift 5.7, when compiling the project I got:

```
Sendability of function types in instance method 'addObserver(forName:object:queue:using:)' does not match requirement in protocol 'NotificationCenterProtocol'
```

Answer (score 6):

**tl;dr**:

If you have a custom protocol and you're conforming an existing class to it, make sure the method signature matches exactly, in this case add `@Sendable` to the closure (after `@escaping`).

---

---

This can happen when you create a protocol and then conform an existing class to it (in this case the native `NotificationCenter`). You have to get the signatures of the methods in your protocol to exactly match the existing signatures in the class.

With the latest update, `@Sendable` was introduced and needs to be added to your custom protocol, so for example for `NotificationCenter` this function needs to say: `[...] using block: @escaping @Sendable (Notification) -> Void`.

Tip:
The easiest way to see the exact function signature is via the 'Developer Documentation' (under 'Help' menu), because there you can see the Swift syntax. If you were to 'Cmd + Click' on `NotificationCenter`, you'd see the methods but with the Objective-C syntax.

Comment: What do you think about this warning then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76251095/sendability-of-function-types-in-property-does-not-match-requirement-in-protocol

Comment: I replied there. An odd mismatch between apparent method signature and what the complier sees. Not sure if it's a bug or something else going on.